# How to replace Image src attr with the one clicked? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one image above four smaller images. When the user clicks one of the smaller images, the smaller image takes the larger images's place. But still remains in it's original spot. I think I'm close to solving it but am in need of help.

HTML

```
        <div class="col-md-8 modal-images">
         <div class="row large-image">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="One.png">
             </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="row small-image">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="One.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="Two.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="Three.jpg">  
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="Four.jpg">
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

JS

```
$('.small-image img').closest('.col-md-4').click(function(){
        var newimage = ($('.small-image img').closest('.col-md-4').find('img').attr('src'));
       $('.large-image img').attr('src', newimage); 
    });
```

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `$(this).`

```js
$('.small-image img').closest('.col-md-4').click(function(){
        var newimage = ($(this).closest('.col-md-4').find('img').attr('src'));
  console.log(newimage)
       $('.large-image img').attr('src', newimage); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8 modal-images">
         <div class="row large-image">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="One.png">
             </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="row small-image">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="One.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="Two.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="Three.jpg">  
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="Four.jpg">
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

***Alternate way***

Its already target with parent .so match with child `img`

```
$('.small-image img').closest('.col-md-4').click(function(){
        var newimage = ($(this).children('img').attr('src'));
  console.log(newimage)
       $('.large-image img').attr('src', newimage); 
    });
```

Comment: wow...four hours of sleep isn't helping. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your fix,` $(this).closest('.col-md-4')` the closest part is incorrect.  Within this handler $(this) refers to the clicked '.col-md-4' element already.

Answer (score 1):

Within the click handler, the 'this' keyword will refer to the .col-md-4 div.  So with that in mind the following works:

```
$('.small-image img').closest('.col-md-4').click(function(){
    var newimage = ($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
   $('.large-image img').attr('src', newimage); 
});
```